# Do I need two keys for AES CBC and HMAC or can I use the same key for both operations?

Tags: keys

I am setting up a Python program to encipher messages on the following basis:

-from my password, generate 32-byte key from SHA256(password)

-generate a 16-byte IV from a PRNG

-measure the length of the plaintext and express as 2 bytes (my plaintext will be shorter than 2^16 characters)

-pad the plaintext to be a multiple of 16 bytes

-make an instance of the encryptor = AES.new(key, CBC, IV)

-generate ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(plaintext)

-make string of concatenated  length pt before padding||IV||ciphertext and send to recipient

-also send to recipient the tag from    HMAC(key,concatenated string)

My question is whether for security I should use a different key for the AES encryption and for the HMAC tagging?

This seems to me unnecessary, in the sense that with a strong password the chance of finding the key by reverse engineering either the ciphertext or the tag is negligible. Or is it?

Comment: Related: [Why can't I use the same key for encryption and MAC?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37880/why-cant-i-use-the-same-key-for-encryption-and-mac)

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise you to use a library with a higher level API, such as Keyczar.

That being said:

- Don't generate the key using SHA-256. [Use a password hash function such as bcrypt or scrypt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-makes-a-hash-function-good-for-password-hashing).
- [Yes, you must use different keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/using-the-same-secret-key-for-encryption-and-authentication-in-a-encrypt-then-ma). For example, you can use the password hash function to generate 64 bytes of key material, and use the first 32-byte half for encryption and the second half for authentication.
- Make sure the IV comes from a good randomness source (e.g. /dev/urandom)
- Make sure your padding is correct. Or simply use CTR which does not require padding.

Comment: Thank you for these inputs. Could you very kindly explain why you recommend a higher level API and also why not use SHA-256 to generate the key?

Comment: Sorry for this unintended duplication ---Thank you for these inputs. Could you very kindly explain why you recommend a higher level API and also why not use SHA-256 to generate the key?

Comment: In a higher level API is easier to avoid mistakes, since they take care of the low-level stuff. The reason for not using SHA-256 is in the link provided in the answer, but in short: it's too fast, which makes brute force attacks faster. Furthermore its output is limited to 256 bits and you may need more for generating both keys.