# About MAC and HMAC

Tags: hash, symmetric, hmac, mac

I'm studying mechanisms of integrity and authentication in symmetric encryption scenarios. I want to propose some examples to see whether I got the point here:

Let $m$ be the message, $c$ the ciphertext, $h$ the hashed message and $t$ the tag resulting of applying MAC.

**Example 1:**

Here Alice wants to send an enciphered message to Bob providing authentication and integrity but without using hash functions. Both parties agree on two different keys, $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$.
Alice applies $c=Enc_{k_{1}}(m)$ and computes $t=MAC_{k_{2}}(m)$. Then she sends $c$ and $t$ to Bob. Bob applies $m=Dec_{k_{1}}(c)$ and verifies $t'=MAC_{k_{2}}(m)$ comparing it to Alice's $t$.

**Example 2:**

Now Alice wants to send an enciphered message to Bob but also hashing the message $m$ for computing the MAC (so HMAC comes in).
Both parties agree on two different keys (again), $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$.
Alice applies $c=Enc_{k_{1}}(m)$, computes the hash over the message $h=H(m)$ and finally computes $t=MAC_{k_{2}}(h)$. She sends $c$ and $t$ to Bob.
Bob now deciphers $m=Dec_{k_{1}}(c)$, computes the hash $h=H(m)$ and verifies the MAC $t'=MAC_{k_{2}}(h)$ comparing it to Alice's $t$.

In case of CBC-MAC, I have read that both parties must agree on a fixed message length, since an attacker could forge a valid MAC. Is this issue solved when using HMAC?

Do you consider these two examples secure? Am I right or mistaken? Specially in the last one, where both parties use hashes with MAC (I have special interest in that one).

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that's not the standard meaning of HMAC; HMAC usually refers to a specific MAC based on a hash function, specifically, $Hash( (OPAD \oplus K) | Hash( (IPAD \oplus K ) | Message ) )$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your scheme:

1. if padding is used then your scheme *may* be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks, this is because decryption happens before MAC verification (see answer of curious);
2. encrypt-and-MAC doesn't provide confidentiality as you can clearly distinguish identical plaintext as the authentication tag $t$ will be identical as well (see the comment of CodesInChaos below the answer of curious).

---

Notes:

- It is a good idea to study [the link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) that curious provides in the answer to understand more of the underlying issues;
- HMAC is a specific construct (using just the hash as underlying primitive); it is *not* hash-then-CBC-MAC;
- The issues of CBC-MAC are readily solved (for block ciphers that use 16 byte block size such as AES) by using the CMAC construction which is based on CBC-MAC but doesn't suffer the same issues for dynamically sized input.

Comment: I found that Mac-Then-Encrypt has been superseded by Encrypt-Then-MAC in TLS when possible. I guess that in some scenarios this isn't supported by both parties. Would be using MtE still considered secure?

Answer (score 1):

Your techniques are not secure. It is the Encrypt and Mac method. Provides integrity to the message but not to the ciphertext. Check this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac). The most secure is to encrypt and then apply the mac to the ciphertext, or to apply an authenticated cipher to the message

Comment: Also the biggest issue with encypt-and-MAC is that it doesn't provide confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all for your replies, specially @Maarten Bodewes who has given a complete answer to my questions.

So thing is that my scheme (Encrypt-and-MAC) doesn't provide confidentiality since the computation of two identical messages yields the samme tag/result. In terms of cryptography it will seem like: $Enc_{k_{1}}(m)$ $||$ $MAC_{k_{2}}(m)$. Notice that it provides integrity.

Also MAC-then-Encrypt is a bad choice since $Enc_{k_{1}}(m || MAC_{k_{2}}(m))$ doesn't provide integrity over the ciphertext.

Best option will be Encrypt-then-MAC: $c=Enc_{k_{1}}(m)$ then send $c$ $||$ $MAC_{k_{2}}(c)$ so confidentiality and integrity are achieved.

I viewed the lesson that covers HMAC here (Princeston University) -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krJ3fHjXYlc Maybe I misunderstood the concept (though the Poncho's answer isn't explained there).

Finally, I would appreciate an explanation of why two keys $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are needed, $k_{1}$ for plaintext encryption and $k_{2}$ for message authentication.

Thanks.

Comment: I've found the answer to my question regarding of the use of two keys for encryption and authentication in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/using-the-same-secret-key-for-encryption-and-authentication-in-a-encrypt-then-ma
We could derive two keys from the SHA-256 of our Master Key, or use a scheme as GCM which permits us to use one key for auth and encryption.